# jquery flot graph displaying week days

Tags: jquery, charts, flot

I am trying to update a flot chart for one week statistics
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5perX/11/) is my code with numbers, Can I change the x axis values to week days? similarly i am trying to show days in month for monthly graph. How to show weekday names instead of numbers

```
<body>
    <div id="placeholder"></div>
</body>


$(document).ready(function () {
    var d1_1 = [
        [1.0, 120],
        [2.0, 70],
        [3.0, 100],
        [4.0, 60],
        [5.0, 35]
    ];

    var d1_2 = [
        [1.0, 80],
        [2.0, 60],
        [3.0, 30],
        [4.0, 35],
        [5.0, 30]
    ];

    var d1_3 = [
        [1.0, 80],
        [2.0, 40],
        [3.0, 30],
        [4.0, 20],
        [5.0, 10]
    ];

    var d1_4 = [
        [1.0, 15],
        [2.0, 10],
        [3.0, 15],
        [4.0, 20],
        [5.0, 15]
    ];

    var data1 = [
        {
            label: "Product 1",
            data: d1_1,
            bars: {
                show: true,
                barWidth: 0.2,
                fill: true,
                lineWidth: 1,
                order: 1,
                fillColor:  "#AA4643"
            },
            color: "#AA4643"
        },
        {
            label: "Product 2",
            data: d1_2,
            bars: {
                show: true,
                barWidth: 0.2,
                fill: true,
                lineWidth: 1,
                order: 2,
                fillColor:  "#89A54E"
            },
            color: "#89A54E"
        },
        {
            label: "Product 3",
            data: d1_3,
            bars: {
                show: true,
                barWidth: 0.2,
                fill: true,
                lineWidth: 1,
                order: 3,
                fillColor:  "#4572A7"
            },
            color: "#4572A7"
        },
        {
            label: "Product 4",
            data: d1_4,
            bars: {
                show: true,
                barWidth: 0.2,
                fill: true,
                lineWidth: 1,
                order: 4,
                fillColor:  "#80699B"
            },
            color: "#80699B"
        }
    ];

    $.plot($("#placeholder"), data1, {
        xaxis: {
            min: 0.0,
            max: 6.0,
            //mode: null,
            ticks: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0],
            tickLength: 0, // hide gridlines
            axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
            axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
            axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
            axisLabelPadding: 5
        },
        yaxis: {
            axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
            axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
            axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
            axisLabelPadding: 5
        },
        grid: {
            hoverable: true,
            clickable: false,
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        legend: {
            labelBoxBorderColor: "none",
            position: "right"
        },
        series: {
            shadowSize: 1
        }
    });

    function showTooltip(x, y, contents, z) {
        $('<div id="flot-tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css({
            top: y - 20,
            left: x - 90,
            'border-color': z,
        }).appendTo("body").show();
    }

    $("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
        var previousPoint;
        if (item) {
            if (previousPoint != item.datapoint) {
                previousPoint = item.datapoint;
                $("#flot-tooltip").remove();

                var originalPoint;

                if (item.datapoint[0] == item.series.data[0][3]) {
                    originalPoint = item.series.data[0][0];
                } else if (item.datapoint[0] == item.series.data[1][3]){
                    originalPoint = item.series.data[1][0];
                } else if (item.datapoint[0] == item.series.data[2][3]){
                    originalPoint = item.series.data[2][0];
                } else if (item.datapoint[0] == item.series.data[3][3]){
                    originalPoint = item.series.data[3][0];
                } else if (item.datapoint[0] == item.series.data[4][3]){
                    originalPoint = item.series.data[4][0];
                }

                var x = originalPoint;
                y = item.datapoint[1];
                z = item.series.color;

                showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY,
                    "<b>" + item.series.label + "</b><br /> " + x + " = " + y,
                    z);
            }
        } else {
            $("#flot-tooltip").remove();
            previousPoint = null;
        }            
    });

});


body { font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; }
#placeholder { width: 450px; height: 200px; position: relative; margin: 0 auto; }
.legend table, .legend > div { height: 82px !important; opacity: 1 !important; right: -55px; top: 10px; width: 116px !important; }
.legend table { border: 1px solid #555; padding: 5px; }
#flot-tooltip { font-size: 12px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; position: absolute; display: none; border: 2px solid; padding: 2px; background-color: #FFF; opacity: 0.8; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -khtml-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modify your `xaxis` tick array to:

```
ticks: [[1.0,"Monday"], [2.0,"Tuesday"], [3.0,"Wednesday"], [4.0,"Thursday"], [5.0,"Friday"]],
```

Update fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5perX/12/).